# Mysql auto increment an user defined variable on fly

Tags: mysql

In my sql, if I write the following code,
`SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 AS index FROM table`, I could get an auto_increment index column, starting from 1.

I just want to understand the rationale behind this query. Why select statement here can be functioning like a "Loop" to loop through all rows?

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The rationale is because mysql implemented it this way. `@i:=@i+1` is an expression and all expressions are calculated in all records, otherwise they would not return the correct value. User-defined variables preserve their values within the active connection, so you get the auto-increment-like behaviour this way.

Pls note, mysql's documentation on [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) mentions that this syntax is deprecated and will probably be removed from future versions:

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

You can use window functions (rank and dense_rank) to achieve the same output from v8.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to understand it as well. And some read over the official documentation doesn't really specify how but once I know the usage of `@` and `:=`, I may have understand how it works.

`@` is for [User-designed variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)
`:=` is for [operator_assign-value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value)

So the first step was to assign a default variable value for the running "auto-increment" by issuing:

```
SET @i := 0;
```

Then in the query you simply write:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1;
```

Let's dissect that. In the first step I have assigned `@i` value to be `0`. If I write `SELECT @i;` after I set them, it will definitely return `0` since I've already assigned it. Then I go to the next query which is used give the "auto-increment" value. Which make me asking if I set the `@i` variable as `0`, shouldn't it take back the assigned value again on the next row? Well, if you look back at the query, it's actually re-assigning the `@i` variable:

[image]

I also have a prepared [an example fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8VMntp4jiFX72CvMaHcuBR/3) with some explanation.

This may not be how it officially work but this is how I understand it.