# Why doesn't order by affect the order of an incremental counter?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table NAMES with 1 column Name. The name column contains bob, amy, chase.

When I run this query below, it returns the result I expect with 1-bob, 2-amy, 3-chase.

```
SET @x:=0;
SELECT @x:=@x+1, Name FROM NAMES;
```

When I run this query below, I expect 2-amy, 1-bob, 3-chase, however instead I get 1-amy, 2-bob, 3-chase.

```
SET @x:=0;
SELECT @x:=@x+1, Name FROM NAMES ORDER BY Name;
```

If order by happens after select, how come the order of the counter isn't affected?

Comment: related-ish, that syntax is deprecated anyway: [Mysql auto increment an user defined variable on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825977/mysql-auto-increment-an-user-defined-variable-on-fly)

Answer (score 1):

As a starter: your original query is not stable. In absence of an `order by` clause, it is undefined how names will be ranked. You need an ordering column, I assumed `id`.

Then: you would need an outer `order by` to do what you want. I also find that it is safer to order in a subquery first, before assigning the rank:

```
set @x:=0;
select *
from (
    select @x:=@x+1 rn, name 
    from (select name from names order by id) t;
) t
order by name
```

Note that you can declare the variable in the same query:

```
select *
from (
    select @x:=@x+1 rn, name 
    from (select name from names order by id) t
    cross join (select @x := 0) x
) t
order by name
```

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is much simpler with `row_number()`:

```
select name, row_number() over(order by id) rn
from names
order by name
```